# Draw a Bar Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, analytics

I know that treating with excel is a piece of cake, but I really need help in representing data in a `Bar Chart`.
The file that I am trying to represent consists of two columns the first is the node number and the second is the ration of consumed energy as shown in [the file.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k4JJicLNXZLk197IJBu4ViZmPNRu7E7l)

The output that I had got is shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3q3i.png) But I want the output to look like [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqlsp.png)
Also, a screenshot for the data that I want to represent is attached [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpCCN.png)

Please if anyone has an idea that could help please let me know.

Comment: please post your screenshots here, so we don't have to leave the site to see them. The file you link to is not usable in any app I have. Please post an Excel file.

Comment: @teylyn Sorry, but I don't have the needed privileges to do that, I can attach an image just using a link as above.